# How to handle network connection in WP8

Tags: windows-phone-8, network-connection

I know there is a method to call to check network, however, if the network suddenly lost, is there anyway I can get some notify event without manual check?

Comment: Not a bad question. Just that your question contains almost all the keywords to get the answer as the first result in Google: "microsoft windows phone 8 network event".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can subscribe to the network changed event which will allow you to know this. See [this topic on MSDN for details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh487166%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).